# 'IAsyncEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: rest, .net-core, async-await

How to solve this issue ?

Service class:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<UserDTO> GetAllUsers()
{
    var allUsers= _userManager.Users.AsAsyncEnumerable();

    await foreach (IdentityUser user in allUsers)
    {
        yield return new UserDTO
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Email = user.Email,
            Password = null
        };
    }
}
```

Interface definition

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<UserDTO> GetAllUsers();
```

Controller

```
private readonly IUserService _userService;

public async IAsyncEnumerable<UserDTO> GetAllUsers()
{
    yield return await _userService.GetAllUsers();
}
```

Full error in controller: `await _userService.GetAllUsers()`

> Error CS1061  'IAsyncEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `await` an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. `await` returns a single instance, while `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is a stream.

You can `await foreach` an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, just like `GetAllUsers` does, and `yield return` each one. But in this case, you *already have* the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` instance, so it makes more sense to just return it directly:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<UserDTO> GetAllUsers()
{
  return _userService.GetAllUsers();
}
```